# mouseover thumbnail to change the main image to the thumbnail at twice the size and main image should link to the same website as thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have studied several similar scripts to my problem and I have tried to modify them to work for me but to no avail. What I'm attempting to do is `mouseover` any thumbnail and change the main image to that particular thumbnail and to render it twice the size. The last thing I'm attempting is to have the main image link to the same website as that thumbnail link. I want to do this in `jquery` with some `css`. I saw something similar to this is in `jsfiddle`. I think where I'm stuck is not being able to fully understand how to change the `src` attribute. I'd appreciate any help.

```
   <div id="header">
 <a href="http://www.pendilum.com" target="_blank">
 <img id="main" src="images/people1.jpg" width="400" height="400"   alt="people">
 </a>
 </div>
 <div id="footer">
 <a href="http://www.pendilum.com" target="_blank">
 <img class="thumbs" src="images/people1.png" width="auto" height="auto"    alt="people">
 </a>
 <a href="http://www.power.com" target="_blank">
 <img class="thumbs" src="images/people2.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="handshake">
 </a>
 <a href="http://www.pants.com" target="_blank">
 <img class="thumbs" src="images/people3.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="peoplejoined">
 </a>
 <a href="http://www.possible.com" target="_blank">
 <img class="thumbs" src="images/people4.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="unisex">
 </a>
 <a href="http://www.yoga.com" target="_blank">
 <img class="thumbs" src="images/people5.png" width="auto" height="auto" alt="yoga">
 </a>
 </div>
```

Here is the JS code

```
  window.onload = function(){
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var mainImg = $("#main");
 $(".thumbs").mouseover(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#main").attr("src",src);
        $(this).css("transform","scale(2)")

    });
 });
 ;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close.

https://jsfiddle.net/j536kzxx/3/

You don't need window.onload if you're using document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var $mainImg = $("#main");
 var $mainLink = $("#header > a");
 $(".thumbs").mouseover(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var link = $(this).parent().attr("href");
    var doubleWidth = $(this).width()*2;
    var doubleHeight = $(this).height()*2;
    $mainImg.attr("src",src);
    $mainImg.css({"width":doubleWidth,"height:":doubleHeight})
    $mainLink.attr("href",link);
    });
 });
```

Get the width/height of the hovered img and apply it to the main img. Get the parent anchor link and apply it to the main anchor link. Voila.

EDIT: The javascript was the problem. Your html was fine, except for one thing. You should set 400px as the width and height of the main img *container*, and not the img itself. This is because you wanted the thumbnails to be double their original size, and not all 400px.

As for parent(), it's not just anchor links. **ALL** html elements except for `<html></html>` can have parents. A parent is simply an element that contains another element.

```
<html>
    <head> <!-- head is child of html, sibling of body -->
    </head>
    <body> <!-- body is child of html, parent of p -->
        <p> <!-- p is child of body, parent of span -->
            <span>Hello World</span> <!-- span is child of p, it is not a parent because it doesn't contain any elements -->
        </p> 
    </body>
<html>
```

It's a hierarchy, or a tree. This image should be useful

[image]

Comment: So you're saying my error is in the html script, not javascript. All the time I was thinking my javascript was the problem. Are you saying that I have to make the my thumbnail the same size as the main image. I didn't know anchor links had a parent property. I have to look that up.

Comment: My main image is really 420 x 420. I added a div container and set it to 420 x 420. The size of my thumbnails is 240 X 240, except the last one that is 276 X 240. I studied your code in jsfiddle and applied it to my shortcomings. Yet I'm still not able to change the main image when I hover any of the thumbnails. Should I resize my thumbnails and make them smaller.

Comment: The size of the thumbnails shouldn't matter in this case. It's still your javascript. Give me a jsfiddle with your imgs (upload them to imgur or something) and i can try to see what's wrong.

Comment: In jsfiddle my code is not working when I run it but your code does.Strange.

Comment: I'd appreciate the help. This has now opened up a can of worms for me. I just learned what imgur is, but the downside is I don't know how to use it. I uploaded and published the images you asked for. I don't know where to find them. I don't know how to upload them to you so you can look at them. I went to the help page but didn't find answers to my questions. I'm stuck.

Comment: Imgur is just an image hosting site, you can use any site you're comfortable with. Can you post the jsfiddle you're working with anyways? It only takes one typo to break the whole thing. The code should work with any images, unless there's a corner case i'm not thinking of.

Comment: Yes I can. Sorry I could not get back sooner. I'm new to jsfiddle but I think I can find the resource to post the jsfiddle.

Comment: This jsFiddle pretty much contains your original code, were you expecting it to work?

Comment: Yes. I am expecting it to work. I'm taking a college course in javascript and I like to try out the exercises given to us.